# Doubt in derivation of Snell's law using Huygen's principle

Tags: optics, refraction, huygens-principle

When we derive Snell's law using Huygen's principle, after refraction, we draw a perpendicular line from the point of intersection of the second light ray with the refracting surface to the first, writing the distance intercepted on the first light ray as $ v_2t $.

I'm having trouble understanding the reason behind the intercepted distance being $ v_2t $. I know it has got something to do with the the two points on the respective light rays lying on a wavefront, but I cannot fully grasp the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a diagram that Huygens produced ([page 35](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonlight031310mbp)) to illustrate what happens when light is refracted.

[image]

**CHHHA** represents a wavefront part of which is about to enter the block travelling at a speed $v_1$.

**LKO** represent wavefronts part of which have entered the block where the speed of the wave is $v_2$ which is less than $v_1$

**BN** is a wavefront which is entirely in the block but would have been wavefront **BMMMO** if the block had not been there.
In the time that point **N** on the wavefront in the block travelled at distance **AN** it would have travelled a distance **AO** (which is equal to **CB**) if the block had not been there.

You have two triangles **ABC** and **AOB** with a common side **AB**.

$CB = v_1t$ and $AN = v_2t$ so now Snell's law can be derived in terms of the sines of the appropriate angles and the velocities in the two different mediums.

[This is a nice simulation which might help?](http://www.walter-fendt.de/ph14e/huygenspr.htm)